# Get the ObjectID from any object I entered based on the display name?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

How can I get the ObjectID from the specific Azure object I entered based on the display name?

The input can be Azure AD App, Azure AD group, or any object type.

```
$objID = ....
```

I require this to simplify the below script:

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $objID `
  -RoleDefinitionName "Contributor" `
  -ResourceGroupName "newly-created-resource-group"
```

based on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azroleassignment?view=azps-9.1.0

Comment: First, u should use the MG graph cmdlets, the AZ module is a thing of the past. You have to query the objects by display name, e.g. -filter "display name eq '$displayname'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to get the object ID using `Get-AzureADApplication`. Below is the PowerShell script that worked for me.

```
$objID = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq '<YourDisplayName>'"
$objID.ObjectId
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]